# Restore DB from single mdf to multiple mdf DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Database that has 800GB single mdf file and I want to restore the Database to that has multiple mdfs.

How can i restore single mdf file database to multiple mdf file database?

Comment: Why is your backup different from the database you're restoring to?

Answer (score 2):

You can't via the RESTORE command.

You need to restore, then create extra filegroups and files, then rebuild the clustered indexes changing the target filegroup.
Each filegroup has one (or more, but I would not have more then 1) ndf files which then achieves what you want.

Comment: Excellent answer. I believe you need to add rebuild clustered index....

Comment: @gbn I dont have any indexes all of my table. How can i rebuild the clustered indexes?

Comment: @S.Zunbag Create and drop the index.

Comment: @gbn Should i create indexes all of my table or just one ?